# Как сделать переменную в if, глобальной

Tags: c++

Нужно сделать простейший калькулятор чтобы он работал с числовыми и строковыми значениями. Операции + - * /

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string answer;
    char type; // тип числа 
    cout << " Введите тип числа (n/s)" << endl;
    while (type != 'n' && type != 's')
        cin >> type;
        if (type == 'n') {  // n = number
         // локальные переменные
         double n1 = 0.0; // числовое значение
         double n2 = 0.0;
       }
        else if (type == 's') { // s = string
       // локальные переменные
        string n1 = 0.0; // строковое 
                       // значение
        string n2 = 0.0; 
       }
        else {
        cout << " Введено неправильное значение";
       }
       // Операции калькулятора
   cout << " Введите число и знак действия. Для выхода из программы введите [q]" << endl;
       while (cin >> answer) {
           if (answer == "q") {
           break;
          }
           cin >> n1;
           else if (answer == "+") { // сложение
           cin >> n2;
           cout << "Сумма " << n1 << " и " << n2 << " равна " << n1 + n2 << endl;
          }
           else if (answer == "-") { // вычитание
           cin >> n2;
           cout << "Разность " << n1 << " и " << n2 << " равна " << n1 - n2 << endl;
          }
           else if (answer == "*") { //умножение
           cin >> n2;
           cout << "Произведение " << n1 << " и " << n2 << " равно " << n1 * n2 << endl;
          }
           else if (answer == "/") { // деление
           cin >> n2;
           cout << "Частное " << n1 << " и " << n2 << " равно " << n1 / n2;
          }
           else {
           cout << "Введите првильный знак";
        }
    }
}
```

Как сделать пременную double n1 n2, или string n1 n2 (в зависимости от ответа) глобальными переменными чтобы использовать их в следующеем цикле ?

Comment: И как Вы будете умножать/делить строки?

Comment: Такой подход не сработает. Типы переменных всегда должны быть известны на этапе компиляции; нельзя их выбирать во время выполнения.

Comment: И где же там фигурируют неизвестные типы?...

Comment: Общее правило: если вам понадобилась глобальная переменная то 99.9% что вы делаете что-то не то.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ой ли ? Поподробнее и с примерами или ссылками на статьи пожалуйста. Я про процент 99.9%. Иногда глобальные переменные всё же нужны.

Comment: @vegorov в том то и дело, что ключевое слово: ингда - это противоположность: пихать везде где вздумается. По поводу статьи - загляните в любую книгу по с/с++ для новичков и там будет написано, что лучше избегать глобальных переменных.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вот [книга](http://python.cs.southern.edu/cppbook/progcpp.pdf) для новичков. В разделе про глобальные переменные нигде не утверждается голословно что вы делаете что-то не так (если используете глобальные переменные), а вполне конструктивно объясняются возможные недостатки и подводные камни, а именно - сложные программы, использующие глобальные переменные, сложнее в чтении/изучении; вводится понятие "независимых" функций, не использующих данные не из своей зоны видимости и объясняется, почему использование таких функций является "желаемым свойством/качеством" программ.

Comment: @vegorov слушайте, я не понимаю к чему вы прицепились: сами же пишете, что автор описывает недостатки глобальных переменных (и какие!) и к чему ведет их использование?